# HTTParty not sending data to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty

I am trying to call a Restful API (basically a third party application). Here is my code:

```
resp = HTTParty.post("http://example.com/test/api/url",
{
:query => {"id"=> 3, "example_payload"=> "test payload", "details"=> {}},
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'client_key' => "xxx-xxx-xxxxx" }
})
```

This is returning a response with status "200 ok". But I am not able to find the changes in my third party application.

I tried with "Rest-client" and "Net-http" as well. Both of them are also not working.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: The httplog gem can help with debugging HTTP requests: https://github.com/trusche/httplog

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by

> "not able to find the changes in my third party application"

, you mean that your not able to hit that third party url.

**Solution:**

You don't need to wrap the query and headers into a hash. Simply pass them as parameters like:

```
HTTParty.post(
"http://example.com/test/api/url",
query: {"id"=> 3, "example_payload"=> "test payload", "details"=> {}},
headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
           'Accept' => 'application/json',    
           'client_key' => "xxx-xxx-xxxxx" 
          }
)
```

This works for me.

Comment: I mean to say, The data is not reflecting the my third party application. But if I post the same from chrome "advanced Rest-client", its working fine